# what does" furnace room" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have read the following paragraph from ***Diary of a Wimpy Kid 3***:

> Ever since Mom assigned the dishes to me and Rodrick, Dad's been going
>   down to ***the furnace room*** after dinner to work on this miniature
>   Civil War battlefield of his.

I am confused about the meaning of "furnace room". I have looked it up in the dictionary.In the dictionary, it means:"a large container for a very hot fire, used to produce power, heat, or liquid metal."

How can he build a furnace room at home. I think it means ***"basement"***,but I can't find this meaning in the dictionary.

Comment: Where I grew up, we had a *utility room* on the first floor with various things including the furnace.  We didn't call it a *basement* because it wasn't below ground level.

Answer (score 6):

Your definition defines *furnace*. A *furnace room* is simply the room where the furnace sits.

In many homes, the furnace is in the basement. In homes with unfinished basements, there is a lot of extra space for storage, or for hobbies such as model trains.

[image: furnace room]

Can't you see Dad setting up his model train set in a room like this one?

Comment: The large box structure with the pipe leading up to the wall is the furnace. In this picture it would be a gas-burning furnace, as opposed to a wood-fire type furnace. Usually home furnaces provide central heating and hot water for the home.

Comment: In British English, that would be called a boiler (if it burns natural gas, or oil).

Comment: @J.R. what is this furnace for in American Family?

Comment: @user48070 - It would be primarily used to heat the home.